# MTG: Abilities lost when exiled?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I used [Glaring Spotlight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlaring%20Spotlight%5d) ability and granted my creatures hexproof and unblockable until end of turn. Then I exiled them with [Legion's Initiative](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLegion%27s%5d%2b%5bInitiative%5d) **after** attacking with [Aurelia, the Warleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAurelia%2c%20the%20Warleader%5d). Do they lose hexproof and unblockable when exiled and come back to the battlefield without hexproof/unblockable? Or will they have that ability until end of turn as stated by glaring spotlight?

Comment: Always remember to go by the Oracle wording; not the wording printed on the cards. They changed "unblockable" to "can't be blocked" to help clarify that "unblockable" is not a keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Your creatures will not have hexproof, but they will be unblockable**

Glaring Spotlight's activated ability creates 2 continuous effects. One grants hexproof, so it changes the objects' "abilities" characteristic. The other  ("creatures you control can't be blocked") modifies the rules of the game. Because of that difference, the first is locked in to the set of objects and will not affect other objects (such as those objects that are created after the blink from Legion's Initiative), whereas the second affects all applicable objects as long as it's active.

> 109.3. An object’s characteristics are name, mana cost, color, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, abilities, power, toughness, loyalty, hand modifier, and life modifier.
>
> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.
>
> 611.1. A continuous effect modifies characteristics of objects, modifies control of objects, or affects players or the rules of the game, for a fixed or indefinite period.
>
> 611.2. A continuous effect may be generated by the resolution of a spell or ability.
>
> 611.2c **If a continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability modifies the characteristics or changes the controller of any objects, the set of objects it affects is determined when that continuous effect begins. After that point, the set won’t change.** (Note that this works differently than a continuous effect from a static ability.) **A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability that doesn’t modify the characteristics or change the controller of any objects modifies the rules of the game, so it can affect objects that weren’t affected when that continuous effect began.** If a single continuous effect has parts that modify the characteristics or changes the controller of any objects and other parts that don’t, the set of objects each part applies to is determined independently.

Comment: Can you clarify why the granting of these two attributes (hexproof and unblockable) are treated so completely differently?  I'm confused.

Comment: I think the unblockability here is actually a _continuous effect_, not a static ability, so your sentence and rules quote about static abilities aren't relevant.

Comment: @John "creatures you control gain hexproof" that gain is the important part, since it gives out the keyword to every creature you control at the time it resolves, the unblockable is actually worded (oracle) as "Creatures you control [...] can't be blocked this turn." which doesn't change the creatures by granting them something, it changes the rules of the game to prevent blocking. Since hexproof is on the creature, when they blink it loses the ability, but since unblockable is on the game itself, it still gets applied to the new creature object after the blink.

Comment: I would avoid using the word "unblockable". The current Oracle wording avoids that on purpose

Comment: I think technically, it creates one instant and one continuous effect. All creatures you control instantly gain hexproof. While the *ability* of hexproof is continuous, the *gain* of hexproof is instant, and only applies to creatures the player control at that moment.

Comment: @Accumulation no, a one - shot effect is something else. "610.1. A one-shot effect does something just once and doesn’t have a duration. Examples include dealing damage, destroying a permanent, creating a token, and moving an object from one zone to another."